# What is the proper way to use registerReceiver in Android 14/SDK 34?

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I'm getting the following warning on the code below

> hardwareScanBroadcastReceiver is missing RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag for unprotected broadcasts registered for an IntentFilter that cannot be inspected by lint

```
registerReceiver(
          hardwareScanBroadcastReceiver,
          scanningHardware.createIntent()
        )
```

But when I added RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED, I'm getting a warning like this

> Field requires API level 33 (current min is 26): android.content.Context#RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED

The minimum SDK version is 26. But how can I implement the registerReceiver and make it backward compatible?

Tried to read the documentation but I didn't find any clue.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Comment: [Use `ContextCompat.registerReceiver()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#registerReceiver(android.content.Context,android.content.BroadcastReceiver,android.content.IntentFilter,int)) and its edition of `RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED`.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare! If you would like to write you answer below instead of a comment, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to [use `ContextCompat.registerReceiver()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#registerReceiver(android.content.Context,android.content.BroadcastReceiver,android.content.IntentFilter,int)) and the `ContextCompat` version of `RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED`. Under the covers, it will check the version of the OS that the app is running on and call the proper real `registerReceiver()` method with the proper flag.

Comment: In the *AndroidManifest.xml* `DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION` is added in the merged manifest. Do you know if it is recommended to remove it via `tools:node="remove"` when the receiver is registered with `RECEIVER_EXPORTED`?

Comment: @JJD: I have no idea, sorry!